# WebSphere MQ Backout Threshold and Backout Name are not working

Tags: jms, websphere, ibm-mq

We have set up `BOTHRESH(5)`, `BOQNAME(USER.ERR)` in WebSphere MQ v7.0.1.9 queue manager.

When TX is rolled back by the MDB in a container managed TX in WebSphere application server v7, the messages are getting placed in DLQ instead of placing in original queue.

I checked the logs which stated that TX got rolled back successfully .

Can some one help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*...the message are getting placed in DLQ instead of placing in original queue.*

Setting `BOQNAME` and `BOTHRESH` results in the QMgr attempting to put the message in something *other than* the original queue.  Once `BOTHRESH` is exceeded, the QMgr will first try to put the message into the queue named by `BOQNAME`, then into the DLQ if putting to `BOQNAME` is not possible.  Only if both of these fail does the QMgr put the message back on the original queue or discard it if the message is non-persistent.

Some reasons that backing out to the queue named in `BOQNAME` or to the DLQ fail are:

1. The target queue does not exist.
2. The target queue is full.
3. The message size exceeds the target queue's MAXMSGL attribute.
4. The user is not authorized to put messages onto the target queue.
5. The target queue is of the wrong type (i.e. XMitQ or model queue).
6. When putting to the DLQ, the QMgr's `DEADQ` attribute is empty.
7. `BOTHRESH` is set but `BOQNAME` is not. In this case, the DLQ is the only queue tried.

Comment: Thanks Rob:)Messages are never placed back in original queue (even  for the very first time when they r rolled back msgs r pushed to  DLQ). 4th point you mean user id with which i'm running the  WAS instance should be authorized to place the msg back to original queue?

Comment: Setting BOQNAME and BOQTHRESH results in the QMgr attempting to put the message in something other than the original queue.(You mean if the remove these properties then by default rolled back msg will always be placed in original queue.I even tired that but still it was landing in dead letter queue:( )

Comment: The user ID that must be authorized is the one that *MQ* thinks is connected.  This may be the WAS instance ID or it may be overridden in the channel's `MCAUSER` or by a channel security exit. `DIS CHS(channel name)` while the channel is running shows the ID that WMQ uses for authorizations in the `MCAUSER` field.  If `MCAUSER` is blank, the channel is running as the WMQ administrator.  If `BOQNAME` and `BOTHRESH`are both empty and messages are landing in the DLQ, it is not due to backout processing.  What is the reason code of the DLQ messages?

Comment: I'm using rfhutil tool to browse remote queues. When i browse SYSTEM.DEAD.LETTER.QUEUE, check the tab(DLQ) i can see the reason code 2362(MQRC_BACKOUT_THRESHOLD_REACHED),BACKCOUNT=0.As per this documentation (http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/0803_titheridge/0803_titheridge.html) default behavior should be place the msg back to original queue since BOTHRESH is not defined.Thanks a lot for you support:)

Comment: we have one scenario when Websphere Application Server (Consumer App) connected with oracle 10g DB.Suppose DB goes down but App server is still up ,msg are read from the queue(API is making destructive get call) but unable to store in DB( to retry later) nor consume it.So we thought if this kind of scenario happens then we will rollback the MDB TX (Container managent TX) so that msg would be placed back to the original queue (Keep it in infinite loop till DB issue is resolved) all msgs are safe in queue.

Comment: Sorry to bug you again .I have observed that when msg is read from the queue(destructive call) later if TX is rolled back msg are placed back to the queue(Original or back out queue). Lets say if something happens(Repeated Network issue or some issue) due to  which rollback of TX got failed then Msgs are lost.Is it true??

Comment: Can you post that as a new question?  The short answer is no but it is not a simple as that.  Depending on the qualities of service used and tuning of the server, the behavior after the failed commit can vary. I can't explain it adequately in a comment.

Comment: Rob can you please respond to my couple of previous questions?I'm struck not able to proceed further:(

Comment: Sorry for the delay. First, Stack Overflow doesn't work like a forum. In order for people to find questions and answers using search, discrete questions are placed in separate posts.  It's all driven by upvotes and question acceptance. Here there's one question about backout behavior, one about transaction reliability over the network and one question about transactional app design. Post, vote, post again, vote again, etc.

Comment: The original question said `BOTHRESH` was set to 5. Your followup question in the comment says "default behavior should be place the msg back to original queue since `BOTHRESH` is not defined." With that reason code, the msg is there because WAS or MQ has set a backout threshold. Either that or somebody's pranking you. Also, the article linked to isn't documentation.  The WAS docs are [here](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r5/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/welcome_ndmp.html).